# In C#, is a Debug.Assert test run in release mode?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, assert

Take the following example:

```
public void Foo()
{
    //Code...

    Debug.Assert(ExpensiveTest());

    //Code...
}
```

What happens to the the `Debug.Assert` method when I compile in release mode? Would `ExpensiveTest()` still run? If not, then how does it work (since it is not a macro that can be set to evaluate to nothing)? If it does run, then doesn't that defeat the purpose of debug assertions?

Comment: It's tagged with the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) so the call gets included only if the calling assembly is compiled with the `DEBUG` symbol being set.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> What happens to the the Debug.Assert method when I compile in release mode?

It's completely removed (including the call to `ExpensiveTest`), assuming you don't have the `DEBUG` conditional compilation symbol defined in your release configuration.

If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx), the declaration uses `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]`:

```
[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
public static void Assert(
    bool condition
)
```

[`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) is used for conditional compilation. See [Bart de Smet's blog post on conditional compilation](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/08/30/4368.aspx) for more details, along with section 17.4.2 of the C# 4 specification.

Answer (score 7):

[Assertions in Managed Code - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcc4x86.aspx)

> In Visual Basic and Visual C#, you can use the Assert method from
>   either Debug or Trace, which are in the System.Diagnostics namespace.
>   **Debug class methods are not included in a Release version of your program**, so they do not increase the size or reduce the speed of
>   your release code.

Also from the same link:

> Note that calls to the **Debug.Assert method disappear when you create
>   a Release version** of your code. That means that the call that checks
>   the balance disappears in the Release version. To solve this problem,
>   you should replace Debug.Assert with Trace.Assert, which does not
>   disappear in the Release version

Answer (score 5):

According to [Debug.Assert Method (Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx) `Debug` methods are compiled only in debug builds.

So, it you build correct release build  (see menu item `Debug/Configuration Manager` for details) this method call will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> Q. In C#, is a Debug.Assert test run in release mode?

The answer is "No." From Microsoft support: [How to trace and debug in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815788):

> You can use the **Trace** and the **Debug** classes separately or
>   together in the same application. In a Debug Solution Configuration
>   project, both **Trace** and **Debug** output are active. The project
>   generates output from both of these classes to all **Listener**
>   objects. However, a Release Solution Configuration project only
>   generates output from a **Trace** class. The Release Solution
>   Configuration project ignores any **Debug** class method invocations.

In particular, the last sentence makes it clear that `Debug.Assert()` statements (as well as other Debug class method invocations) are ignored in a Release build.